# Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Is Theorem true in the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Then there is not a collection of
open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that is both pairwise disjoint and uncountable. Is Theorem true in the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Proof: We know that, On $\mathbb{N}$, cofinite topology $T_{cf}$ is the topology consisting of $\emptyset$ and all complements of finite sets. Here, we have $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, our claim is no two proper sets of $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology are disjoint. Let us consider, $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be two proper open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology, 
therefore, $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A_1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A_2$ are both finite.
Therefore, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are infinite set.
So, $A_1$ $\cap$ $A_2$ = $\emptyset$ which implies that $A_2$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ \ $A_1$ and this is finite, which is not possible.
Therefore, $A_1$ $\cap$ $A_2$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$, for any two proper open sets $A_1$ and $A_2$.
If we take, $\mathbb{R}$ $\cap$ $\mathbb{Q}$ = $\mathbb{Q}$, then the complements will work. Therefore, this theorem is true for $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology.

Kindly verify and let me know if this theorem looks good. If there is something needed to change, kindly let me know. If it needs a better notation, do let me know. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cofinite topology on an infinite sets indeed has the property that any two non-empty open sets intersect. So a fortiori the space is ccc (that's the name of the property that any pairwise disjoint family of *non-empty* open sets is at most countable). Your proof is fine.

Comment: I am glad 2 hear that my proof is fine, but I didnt get the property u talked about. I didnt find it in my notes which my prof sent to me. Is it available in Munkres or topology without tears? Also, is it good to mention this in my proof or add it?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun the property is not named in elementary text books, usually. But it's a common term in topological papers. You don't have to know the name, but you do ask about it.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks a lot for telling me that.